# Vuex await promise before performing router actions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is my first project working with Vue and Vuex. I have set up a few routes where each requires an authenticated user except the login route. Everything works fine until the page gets refreshed.

This is my router:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(x => x.meta.requiresAuth)
    let user = await store.getters.loggedIn
    if (requiresAuth && !user) {
        console.log("Is user logged in?", user)
        next("/login")
    } else {
        console.log("Is user logged in?", user)
        next()
    }
})
```

If the user visits the page the first time he gets redirected to the login page. After the user logs in sucessfully the `loggedIn` value in the store gets set. The user can now move around the site without having to reauthenticate again.

Store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        loggedIn: false,
    },
    getters: {
        loggedIn(state) {
            return state.loggedIn
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setLoggedIn(state, val) {
            state.loggedIn = val
        },
    },
    actions: {
        loggedIn({commit}, user) {
            if (user) {
                commit("setLoggedIn", true);
                console.log("USER FOUND: ", true)
            } else {
                commit("setLoggedIn", false);
                console.log("NO USER FOUND: ", false)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

If the user refreshes the page the console log of the router part will be:

```
Is user logged in? false
STATE CHANGED
USER FOUND:  true
```

This is my main.js:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  console.log("STATE CHANGED: ", user)
  store.dispatch("loggedIn", user);
});

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app")
```

My guess is that the `onAuthStateChanged` from the main.js doesn't force the rest to wait for its result. How should I handle this issue?

Comment: Vuex getters and mutations always run synchronously - there is no need to put `await` when you call a Vuex getter. Only Vuex actions can potentially be asynchronous.

Comment: Why are you using await if you dont need it

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the user data also in browser LocalStorage then retrieve that data across page refreshes.
First use LocalStorage.setItem('user', userData) to store user data when he/she logged in.
Then in your state:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loggedIn: localStorage.getItem('user') ? true : false, // the key part
  }
})
```

Comment: localstorage does not have a lifetime like session variables, the user will not be logged out until the localstorage variable is deleted or modified. It's just a remark.